# Custom Directory for SSH Identity Files

Tags: ssh, openssh, macos

**Is there a way to specify a different default directory for ssh identity files?**

Normally, the default directory is `~/.ssh`, but I would like to specify (in the `.ssh/config` file I assume) a different location.

I can do this with individual hosts in the `.ssh/config` file using the `IdentifyFile` config option:

```
Host foo foo.bar 
    HostName foo.bar
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-ssh-keys/id_rsa
    User foouser
```

What I would like to do is, for example, have `~/.ssh/my-ssh-keys` be the default directory.  I can't seem to find an option for it listed in [Listing of client configuration options](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config#listing-of-client-configuration-options).  Is there a way to override the default directory location?

Comment: I've perused the entire `man ssh_config` and I've been unable to find anything relevant aside from `Include` which allows to include more configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

ssh does not have a default directory for identity files, so I'm not sure what you are asking.

You can specify a default identity file using

```
Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-ssh-keys/id_rsa
```

I did not test this but according to the docs you could also use

```
Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-ssh-keys/id_rsa
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-ssh-keys/id_dsa
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my-ssh-keys/id_ecdsa
    # etc.
```

if that is what you are after.

Comment: I does have a default location.  It checks two locations:  `/etc/ssh` (depending on your system) and `~/.ssh` this is per the OpenSSH documentation. This answer specifies a default *key* for all hosts, not a default *location* to search for a key.

Comment: @Allan you asked for a "default directory for ssh identity files" - /etc/ssh does not store identity files. ssh only has a few hardcoded identity files it checks and you can override all with the second part of my answer. Maybe you can update your question with what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What I want to achieve is clearly articulated in the question.  On my Mac and on my FreeBSD box, in `/etc/ssh` there, are identity files.  Reading `man ssh_config` states that it will try, during authentication, each file in both the systemwide and user ssh directory.  So, if you have multiple keys in `~/ssh` it will go though each one and try it.  I want to specify a different directory that it will look in.

Comment: Identity files are per user, it wouldn't make sense to put them into /etc/ssh.